# How to capture user who triggered Airflow DAG

Tags: airflow, rbac

I've enabled RBAC as environment variable in docker-compose file.

```
- AIRFLOW__WEBSERVER__RBAC=True
```

I want to capture the user who kicked off a dag inside my dag files.

I tried using `from flask_login import current_user`. But, I get the value of `current_user` as None.

May I know how to capture user details using RBAC?

Answer (score 0):

According to [Airflow](https://airflow.apache.org/) documentation as part of [RBAC](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/security.html#rbac-ui-security) security model that is handled by *Flask AppBuilder (FAB)*:

> Airflow uses `flask_login` and exposes a set of hooks in the
>   `airflow.default_login` module. You can alter the content and make it
>   part of the `PYTHONPATH` and configure it as a backend in
>   `airflow.cfg`.

[*Flask-login*](https://github.com/maxcountryman/flask-login) module provides user management operations, thus you can fetch current user within a dedicated property [flask_login.current_user](https://flask-login.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#flask_login.current_user), adding 
some extra fields, as described in [#3438](https://github.com/apache/airflow/pull/3438) pull request:

```
if current_user and hasattr(current_user, 'user'):
    user = current_user.user.username
elif current_user and hasattr(current_user, 'username'):
```

I suppose that you can use `current_user.user.username` to fetch a user login.

Comment: This does not work anymore in Airflow 2.1.0. ```AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'user'```